# Cant adding a TIFF to a pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, tiff, pdfbox

Im trying to add a TIFF image (CCIT Group 3) to a PDF using Java and PDFBox 1.8.10. There is an image shown on the output file, but its displayed wrong. Its only some black and white pixels.

```
    String outputPath = "/tmp/PDFImage.pdf";
    String imagePath = "/tmp/header.tif";

    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

    PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDCcitt(doc, new RandomAccessFile(new File(imagePath), "r"));

    content.drawImage(ximage, 0, 500);

    content.close();
    doc.save(outputPath);
    doc.close();
```

The PDFBox dependencies says : To write TIFF images a JAI ImageIO Core library will be needed. 
I imported the library and and scanned for plugins, but dont found an example how to use is exactly. Someone can help ?

Comment: What library did you use? It should be jai_imageio.jar. Can you upload the tif file and the pdf?

Comment: Oh, i saw the import is for javax.ImageIO. Now I added JAI ImageIO 1.01, but I dont know what exactly to do with the lib ? Unfortunately I cant upload any of this.

Comment: add it to the library list in your IDE. If you don't know how, add the name of your IDE to the question (netbeans, eclipse, intellij, whatever).

Comment: Iam using Eclipse and added the jar file to the project, but its still the same result.

Comment: Then you should really upload the tif and the result PDF somewhere so that I can have a look. To be sure that this isn't a PDFBox bug.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant publish it. Its stuff from the company... Is there also a need for scanForPlugins() ? How can I do this with JAI lib ?

Comment: No there isn't. You only need to have the jar file in your classpath. Alternatively, create a non confidential TIFF file from scratch (with a graphics software, e.g. irfanview) and see if it works.

Comment: I did not know that irfanview can create t.4 images. I looked in the internet for another example, but could not find. The new created image works perfectly... seems my image is the problem. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Plan B for you: read the image with ImageIO.read() into a BufferedImage, and then use PDPixelMap. (But you'll still need jai_imageio.jar for this)

Comment: Unfortunately plan b doesnt work with TIF, it throws a NullPointerException...

Comment: Create a new question, or post on the PDFBox user mailing list. We'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks, but first I have to check how the image is read, because I generate the TIFF header myself. Its displayed fine, but maybe the header is malformed or something. After converting to PNG, PDFBox works fine with. Its also not working if I convert the raw t4 data with fax2tiff (libtiff-tools).

Comment: Another possible explanation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3299 (FillOrder=2). I've also just created a possibility to use CCITT compression for b/w BufferedImages https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3069